# Coin Toss - Category of counting

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am struggling with a concept although I do understand the solution.

Question : you toss a coin 5 times, how many different solutions do you expect?
Solution: n^k = 32

So my idea was to solve it differently by using permutations. I take 5 coin tosses and model it like a word with 5 Hs and 5 Ts. Next is count n=10 and I have to pick k=5 permutations.
So my alternative idea was to ask the question how many ways you have to arrange a word with 5 elements of
“HHHHHTTTTT”

Basically I want to know if I can calculate the result with permutation with repitions?

10! / ((10-5)!

Can someone explain to me why modelling this coin toss as a permutation is failing?

Thank you

Comment: This is not clear.  First of all, I think you are using "expect" in a non-standard way (at least for probability).  Expectation suggests that you want to compute the mean of some distribution but here I think all you intend to say is that there are $2^5=32$ possible outcomes.  Why you write this as $>32$ I don't know.  Secondly...why do you switch ffrom $5$ tosses to $10$?

Comment: Hello, I want to model it as a permutation. 

Imagine your 5 coin tosses would generate a word with 10 characters. Every coin toss adds two characters, so you end up with a pool of HHHHHTTTTT.

Comment: You want to model $\textit {what}$ as a permutation?  The space of possible length five binary sequences is not a permutation in any sense I can think of.  And why would a single coin toss add two characters?  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: I don’t know how to explain it differently. I just imagine 5 coin tosses and every toss provides H or T as outcome. So I was thinking if it was possible to solve the question from another point of view. 
instead of tossing a coin 5 times I assume I have a word “HHHHHTTTTT” and pick 5 characters and calculate how many arrangements there are. 

So I represent the result of 5 coin tosses as a word e.g. “HHHHH” or “HTHTH” or “TTTTT”, etc.

Comment: I don't understand.  A binary string of length $k$ is determined by the $k$ choices you make, hence there are $2^k$ such strings. I don't understand why you are doubling the length of your string.  For example, one possible binary string is $TTTTT$.  How do you see that particular string as a length $10$ string with five Heads and five Tails?

Comment: I’ll try one last time... imagine you take an urn. Put in 10 balls on which 5 have H and 5 have T on it. Wouldn’t it represent the same concept of 5 coin tosses when you can pick 5 balls? Hence i think of a 10 characters word where I pick 5 of them for an arrangement. I am simply trying to represent the coin toss as a give string of characters. If it was 8 coin tosses my word would be 16 characters etc

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't make sense.  That's why the numbers aren't working out.  If your urn contains $5$ of each then, say, the last one you draw is not a fair coin toss (since it is determined by the others you have drawn).  More broadly, the probability that the next draw is Heads is a function of your prior draws, which is not true for a fair coin.  I don't think the analogy you are trying to draw is helpful.

Comment: But you would return the ball to the urn, so it’s still 10 balls for every draw

Comment: But then what's the point of having five of each?  In your post you specifically say that your length $10$ words should have exactly five Heads.  Sorry, I don't think you have thought this through.  Try writing out your idea in complete detail for length $3$.  In that case, there are only $2^3=8$ sequences, while there are $\binom 63=20$ strings of length $6$ containing three Heads and three Tails.  What do you want to do with that set up?

Comment: @Pr4ma, you might first explore how (or whether) your idea works in a smaller setting, say tossing a coin two or three times (or maybe even just once!), where you can much more easily write down all the different outcomes involved. (Ah, I see lulu just suggested much the same thing.)